# ODE, a first order none-linear equation with ratios and exponents

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I have this equation that I don't know how to approach:
$$xy'-y=xe^{\frac{y}{x}}$$
I don't even know if the solution is a function of variable $x$ or $y$.
I don't know how to start. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: $x$ is the independent variable. Try dividing by $x$ and making the substitution $u=\dfrac{y}x$. Note that

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}(xu)=x\frac{du}{dx}+u\;.$$

Answer (score 3):

This equation is Homogeneous Ordinary Differential Equation. By variable $"y=vx"$, it turned into a simple separable equation.

Answer (score 1):

$$xy'-y=xe^{y/x}$$

$$y'-\frac{y}{x}=e^{y/x}$$

Let $y=vx\Rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx}=v+x\frac{dv}{dx}$, Then we have,

$$v+x\frac{dv}{dx}-v=e^v\Rightarrow\frac{dv}{e^v}=\frac{dx}{x}$$

Hope you can solve it now.